# Авторизация на сайте через php

Tags: php, curl, авторизация

Пытаюсь авторизоваться на сайте e-autopay. Однако получаю ошибку 500. Уже все перепробовал. Подскажите, в чем ошибка?
Может кто-нибудь сможет протестить код. Уверен решение элементарное.

Логин и пароль действующие

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
function request($url,$post = 0){
$ch = curl_init();
$ref="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.65 Safari/537.36";    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$request = 'Host: giggle.e-autopay.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: https://giggle.e-autopay.com
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: https://giggle.e-autopay.com/adminka/login
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4';
$split = explode("\n",$request);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$split ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ref);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 400);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt'); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, $post!==0 );
if($post)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '_token='.urlencode($post).'&login='.urlencode('giggle').'&password='.urlencode('45ne6w'));
$curl=curl_exec($ch);
$data = new simple_html_dom();
$data->load($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($ch);
var_dump($status);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}
$url = 'https://giggle.e-autopay.com/adminka/login';
$token = request($url,0);
echo $token = $token->find('input[name=_token]',0)->value;
echo request($url,$token);
```

Comment: 500 ваш скрипт отдаёт или ответ ebay?

Comment: e-autopay. Мой скрипт выводит:  ["http_code"]=> int(500)

Comment: так потому что сервак отдаёт 500

Comment: так я это знаю. Поэтому и задаю вопрос. Почему сервак выдает 500?

Answer (score 1):

Как найти элементарную ошибку в коде.

- Включить вывод ошибок вплоть до нотайсов, установкой данной опции в начале скрипта

  `error_reporting(E_ALL);` или в php.ini
   `error_reporting E_ALL` и   `display_errors 1`
- Просто прочитать error log php
- Прочит ошибку `Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given`
- задуматься о ней исправить.
- Идём по url в скрипте https://giggle.e-autopay.com/adminka/login получаем 
  500.

Вывод: не работает скрипт, и сервер.

Comment: включил, прочитал, задумался, исправил, Ошибка остается.
Если в первом случае, без параметров, сервер отдает 200, то при попытке послать туда post-данные, выдает 500. Хотя через браузер все нормально открывается

Comment: @user2244523 всё ясно просто надо зайте сначала сессию получить взять токен и вторым запросом уже авторизовываться.

Comment: @user2244523 проверь создался ли файл с куками и установилась сессия.

Comment: да, в первом случае я получаю токен, потом отправляю его вместе с логином и паролем в пост-запросе вторым запросом. Файл с куками создается.

Comment: @user2244523 надо первым токен в сессии храниться т.е. если сессии нет то сколько хочешь запрашивай он не совпадёт

Comment: Не совсем понимаю. Я с помощью $url = 'https://giggle.e-autopay.com/adminka/login';
$token = request($url,0); иду на страницу, для меня создается сессия, я забираю с скрытого поля токен и затем вместе с логином и паролем на эту же страницу отправляю ээтот токен . Или как-то по другому надо делать?

Comment: Ну да но по всей видимости сессия пересоздаёться